# Bad argument in cornerHarris function

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to find corners in my image by Harris Detector, but I have a problem when i run this code:

```
int blockSize = 2;
int apertureSize = 3;
double k = 0.04;

IplImage* binMaxMatchContourImage = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(maxMatchContourImage), 8, 1);
IplImage* afterHarrisImage = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(maxMatchContourImage), 8, 1);

cvCanny(maxMatchContourImage, binMaxMatchContourImage, 50, 200);
cvCornerHarris( binMaxMatchContourImage, afterHarrisImage, blockSize, apertureSize, k);
```

But my program failed:

```
OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp, line 698
```

Please, explain me, where is my problem?

Comment: You'll get more attention to your question if you post a SSCCE (http://sscce.org/)

Comment: what type is `maxMatchContourImage`?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether maxMatchContourImage is of the same type and size as maxMatchContourImage. Both should be single channel images for Canny edge detection to work.

If this condition is met, cvCornerHarris should work.